Black pixelated line around rendered video
I am a complete beginner in Blender, a friend of mine sells t-shirts and asked if i could create a 3D walking animation for his shirts. I found a tutorial and created what he is looking for. I rendered it as png sequence then stitched it together in Blender, it looked great but I put it into DaVinci Resolve to add a background. I now have a black outline around the object. I tried searching for this of course and only came across the 'freestyle' option, however this was already unchecked. Any advice to fix this would be greatly appreciated. And I apologise if this is a question for DaVinci users. Thanks in advance.

what did you import in DaVinci, a png sequence or a video file?
